# Change email sender - Android

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send an automatic email from my app. I've tried many tutorials and only one of them has worked. The problem is that I want to change the sender from an email to a name.

[image: This is an image previewing the email sent].

And these are the working codes (I don't know why the other ones on the tutorials didn't):

***GMail.java***

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import android.util.Log;

public class GMail {

    final String emailPort = "587";// gmail's smtp port
    final String smtpAuth = "true";
    final String starttls = "true";
    final String emailHost = "smtp.gmail.com";

    String fromEmail;
    String fromPassword;
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    String toEmailList;
    String emailSubject;
    String emailBody;

    Properties emailProperties;
    Session mailSession;
    MimeMessage emailMessage;

    public GMail() {

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public GMail(String fromEmail, String fromPassword,
                    String toEmailList, String emailSubject, String emailBody) {
        this.fromEmail = fromEmail;
        this.fromPassword = fromPassword;
        this.toEmailList = toEmailList;
        this.emailSubject = emailSubject;
        this.emailBody = emailBody;

        emailProperties = System.getProperties();
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", emailPort);
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", smtpAuth);
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", starttls);
        Log.i("GMail", "Mail server properties set.");
    }

    public MimeMessage createEmailMessage() throws AddressException,
            MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(emailProperties, null);
        emailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

        emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail, fromEmail));

        Log.i("GMail","toEmail: "+toEmailList);
        emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(toEmailList));


        emailMessage.setSubject(emailSubject);
        emailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");// for a html email
        // emailMessage.setText(emailBody);// for a text email
        Log.i("GMail", "Email Message created.");
        return emailMessage;
    }

    public void sendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException {

        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(emailHost, fromEmail, fromPassword);
        Log.i("GMail","allrecipients: "+emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
        Log.i("GMail", "Email sent successfully.");

    }


}
```

***SendMailTask.java***

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class SendMailTask extends AsyncTask {

    private Activity sendMailActivity;

    public SendMailTask(Activity activity) {
        sendMailActivity = activity;

    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... args) {
        try {
            Log.i("SendMailTask", "About to instantiate GMail...");
            publishProgress("Processing input....");
            GMail androidEmail = new GMail(args[0].toString(),
                    args[1].toString(),  args[2].toString(), args[3].toString(),
                    args[4].toString());
            publishProgress("Preparing mail message....");
            androidEmail.createEmailMessage();
            publishProgress("Sending email....");
            androidEmail.sendEmail();
            publishProgress("Email Sent.");
            Log.i("SendMailTask", "Mail Sent.");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            publishProgress(e.getMessage());
            Log.e("SendMailTask", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Object result) {

    }


}
```

And in ***MainActivity.java*** the onButtonClick method:

```
String fromEmail = "email@gmail.com";
String fromPassword = "email-password";
String toEmails = "toEmail@gmail.com";
String emailSubject = "App Registration Mail";
String emailBody = "Your message";
new SendMailTask(PlayerMainActivity.this).execute(fromEmail, fromPassword, toEmails, emailSubject, emailBody);
```

And for sure the 3 jar files are added in the `libs` folder.

I want to change the email in the email (which is email@gmail.com) to a specific name (for example The App Team). How can I do that?

Comment: You can try `String fromEmail = "The App Team <email@gmail.com>";`. Also note that attackers will grab your email account details from the APK and use that for sending spam or other nasty things. Send emails from your Web service, not from the client.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am using my own email for this. But anyway, how can I do what you suggested?

Comment: @CommonsWare mean to say that you should avoid sending emails from client but you can use an api(for sending emails ) for that because app can be decompiled which will lead you to trouble!

Comment: @SumitShukla I tried searching for some APIs but didn't find any one.

Comment: I don't know about apis but you can create your own with a web-service in php or some other language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail, fromEmail));
```

with

```
emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail, "Sender Name Here"));
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But can I don't want the ```fromEmail```. I just want the Sender's name. I tried it but it is not working.